# EF 4.1 model first code generation tool or template

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Is there a template or tool to generate code from the database directly? I want to use model first scenario but do not want .edmx file for mappings. There is a database with many tables and I do not want to write all the classes (I am lazy) for that. So, is there a template to generate the code and set the annotations/use fluent api for defining the relationships, etc automatically from the existing database?

This would be helpful in the following scenario as well. Say, I was using .edmx with POCOs and now I do not want the mappings in the .edmx file. I want the mappings in the code. It would be great to have a tool or a template to generate the mappings in the code from the existing database.

I am starting on learning EF 4.1. I think "Code first becomes model first in version 2 i.e. after the database is created/released (in version 1) and needs some changes". Is that really true? I'd love to hear some comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the 'Reverse Engineer Code First' feature of the [EF Power Tools CTP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx) that was just released.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. It lacks some features though but hey it's the first version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For generating classes, you can use POCO t4 template generation. Have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) detailed link which will help you getting started. That way you will get all the classes generated.

For mapping, you can use Code-Only style for Entity Framework but generating classes and context using POCO template will have far more advantage over creating the mapping yourself. Imagine adding new tables or modifying the tables, it will involve more work. But I will certainly love to know if there is any mapping tool for that.

Comment: I do not want .edmx file for mappings. I want it in the code.

Comment: I currently use .edmx with oracle and it is a pain as the store generated identity inserts are lost if I make any modification and save it. If the mappings are in the code, I don't have to change it. I can have much more control in the code than .edmx file.

Comment: Yeah agreed. I knew how to get the classes generated (even I am lazy), which I used myself. Didn't knew of any mapping tool though. Great to know from Dave's answer

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using EF-provider Devart dotConnect for Oracle when working with Oracle database. In this case the following information will help you to choose the tool.

The first version of  Entity Framework Power Tools also contained the capability of generating a Code-First model with fluent mapping from an existing database. Although useful, this functionality is limited as regards its flexibility: the developer can only set the connection string; following that, classes are generated from all database objects available to the user. That is not extremely convenient, since in Oracle, for example, numerous schemas containing hundreds and sometimes thousands of tables are available to the user.

Rather than resort to this limited functionality, the users of Devart ADO.NET providers can avail themselves of impressively robust design-time development capabilities of Entity Developer, an EF-designer delivered with Devart providers. Also possible is the choice between the Database-First approach, as provided in EF Power Tools, and the Model-First approach, within which Code-First classes are created in the EDM-designer.

When compared to  EF Power Tools, the  Database-First approach to the development of EF Code-First models also allows selecting objects that must be available in the model, setting naming rules for the generation of class names and properties and so on. Besides, the resulting model can be modified and improved in the designer.

To better meet developers' needs, Code-First code generation in  Entity Developer both for C# and VB is based on the T4-template that is easily accessible and can be modified in feature-rich T4 Editor contained in  Entity Developer.

For more information on Code-First development in Entity Developer, see "Entity Developer – EF Code First DbContext Template"
http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-developer-ef-code-first-dbcontext-template.html